# Capture Android ISO, Exposure, Aperture using camera2 API

Tags: android, cordova

I have a cordova plugin written for iOS that streams camera information, but having a hard time converting it to Android. Thanks to reading the camera2 API and https://inducesmile.com/android/android-camera2-api-example-tutorial/, I've come made *some* progress.

I'm hoping to not actually create an image to get camera values, and it seems that this is done issues a `captureRequest` on a `Surface`?

I declare some class variables

```
CameraManager manager;
CameraDevice cameraDevice;
CaptureRequest.Builder builder;
String cameraId;
protected final String TAG = "STREAMLINX_CAMERA";
CallbackContext callbackContext;
```

When the view is loaded I issue a `start()`

```
    public void start() {
        this.manager = (CameraManager) cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        this.cameraId = this.getCameraId(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT);

        if (!cordova.hasPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            cordova.requestPermission(this, 0, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        } else {
            this.callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "success"));
            try {
                this.manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Then within the cordova app, I have a setInterval every 500ms that runs a `capture()`

```
public void capture() {
    Log.d(TAG, "capture");
    builder.build();
    Log.d(TAG, "APERTURE: " + builder.get(CaptureRequest.LENS_APERTURE));
    Log.d(TAG, "ISO: " + builder.get(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY));
    Log.d(TAG, "EXPOSURE: " + builder.get(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME));
}
```

..and some of my helping hands

```
private String getCameraId(int orientation) {
    try {
        for (String cameraId: this.manager.getCameraIdList()) {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = this.manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            Log.d(TAG, "RANGE: " + characteristics.get(SENSOR_INFO_SENSITIVITY_RANGE);
            if (characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == orientation) {
                return cameraId;
            }
        }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }

    return null;
}

private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
        cameraDevice = camera;
        try {
            builder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_MANUAL);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
        cameraDevice.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
        cameraDevice.close();
        cameraDevice = null;
    }
};
```

I believe I need to change my `createCaptureRequest` to be some form of a `createCaptureSession` and use `Surface`, but not sure if that is over thinking it as I look at some of the code samples.

Am I missing some API features that would get the current state of the camera?